# Does typecasting of Vector to ArrayList cause any issue?

Tags: java, casting

We are working on a very old java project and most of the List objects are declared as Vector.
Sonar is complaining about the use of Vector that is synchronized.

```
List vector = new Vector();
```

We can easily change the declaration to Arraylist but I'm worried that it may cause an issue somewhere else in the codebase where synchronization happens or there is a specific scenario that expects Vector.

Can someone advise if it is fine to typecast Vector to ArrayList or simply changing the declaration to ArrayList and be used as Vector in other parts of the code?

Note: Reflection is being used a lot in the framework and the ArrayList object can be retrieved and may be cast again to Vector.

Comment: No. It is **not** safe to cast a `Vector` to `ArrayList` (or vice-versa). This code is using raw types, but collections interfaces. Very odd.

Comment: Casting only fools the compiler. It doesn't affect the actual class used.

Comment: Perhaps you should post another Question about the specifics of the Sonar complaint.

Comment: I would be amazed when Vector's synchronicity were used, and at some time you want to replace Vector. I would also refrain from endlessly doing small refactorings repeatedly visiting the same sources. Only make an inventory, listing of all sources and their conversion state. In a spreadsheet with a time line you can then follow the progress to 100%.

Answer (score 2):

If you do something like:

```
List myVar = new Foo();
```

Then the Foo class must implement the List interface.  Both Vector and ArrayList do this, as do many-many other classes.  Having stated the obvious, what you need to realize is that thereafter, in every line of code and method call, you are basically restricted to dealing with 'myVar' as if it is ONLY a "List".  The actual implementation happens to be a "Foo" implementation, but no one should know or care.  They are simply looking to do list-like-things on an entity that should-be-a-list.

If you change the right-hand-side from Vector-to-ArrayList, but the left-hand-side was always a "List", in principle, all will be well (mostly).  Every well-behaved actor should be dealing with it as if it's an arbitrary "List" (and it still is).  Some bad actor might be casting the "List" they got into something else (e.g. a Vector), but that's a bad practice - you'd likely want to go fix that other code anyway.  The Java compiler has a few 'lint' warnings that can help you find places where bad-actors upcast.

In my experience, this kind of change is pretty risky.  Code that old and poorly written is likely ripe with bugs, and you are wading into the mindfield with a blind-fold on.  Unless your purpose is to update the code, and are willing to accept introducing bugs due to conversion, I wouldn't take it on.  Sonarqube is correct, that's some bad code.  But if it's beyond the scope of what you are working upon, use the appropriate SuppressWarning to tell SonarQube to ignore it on this piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

Casting doesn't change the class of an object. The place to use casts is where the code doesn't have information about what class something is, but you do. Adding a cast lets you give that information to the code. But if you are wrong about the cast then the cast will throw an exception.

So putting a cast on a Vector doesn't make it an ArrayList. But in this case it's not even allowed to compile, this code:

```
Vector<String> v = new Vector<>();
ArrayList<String> a = (ArrayList)v;
```

results in this compile error:

> incompatible types: java.util.Vector<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList

because the compiler knows better than to let you tell it that this object it already knows the type of is really some unrelated class. So casting is not an option. Consider being very skeptical of any technical guidance coming from the person who gave you that advice.

Figuring out whether these Vectors can be replaced by ArrayLists is going to be tricky, because it means understanding what the legacy code is doing well enough to be able to say for sure that you didn't break anything. Insufficient synchronization is something that is really hard to test for, and the risk is that you miss something and it fails in production. And these things are typically not noisy failures, typically they will fail silently and you won't know about it until something (or worse, someone) downstream complains. So if the only reason to make this change is because of the sonarqube warning, my advice is to suppress the warning and leave the code alone.

The reason that the sonarqube rule is there is because the synchronization on Vector is not very useful in practice (the lock granularity is all wrong), and there is a cost to acquiring the lock even when it's uncontended. However, the cost of uncontended synchronizations is something that the JVM developers have worked hard to bring down. If you can upgrade this application to use a recent JVM you might get some benefit, if that is what is going on, without the risk of making code changes.